# Finding the next biggest value in the array C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of 5 chars and a char '4', I would like to find the next biggest value in the array which would be a '6'. How would i go about doing this?

Thanks guys

```
char findNextBiggestValue = '4';
char array[5] {'3','6','7','8','9'};
```

Comment: Is `array` sorted? And what you already tried?

Comment: `next biggest value`? Base on your example, I think what you want is finding the smallest value greater than '4'.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, first sort, then filter:

```
char findNextBiggestValue = '4';
char array[5] {'3','6','7','8','9'};
var val = array.OrderBy(s => s).FirstOrDefault(x => x > findNextBiggestValue);
```

OR

```
var val = array.Where(x => x > findNextBiggestValue).Min();
```

Comment: This returns an incorrect result if the (filtered) array is empty.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
char findNextBiggestValue = '4';
char[] array = new [] { '3','6','7','8','9'};

char min = array.Where(c => c > findNextBiggestValue).Min();
```

This performs faster than a sort as it will only do a single iteration over the array. LINQ's operator chaining works with `.Where(...)` and `.Min()` operations very efficiently.

This code also returns an exception if there are no elements returned by the `.Where(...)` operator. This is by design as a `char` is a value type that must have an operator and it would be a bug to return any value as a default.

The other option would be to return a `char?` instead and have the `null` value represent no return result.

In this case the code would look like this:

```
char? min = array.Where(c => c > findNextBiggestValue).Cast<char?>().Min();
```

Comment: May I ask, compare to my answer, do everything manually, which way has a better performance?

Comment: @AnhTriet - They are much the same - so would imagine they have the same performance. Yours fails if the array contains chars greater than `z though.

Comment: Yes, I know. So, I comment that init it with a large value. 'z' is just an example, we can get the largest char using ASCII table. But I think we often know how large our data is :)

Comment: Just an FYI, this doesn't do a single iteration over the array. It will do one iteration for the `Where`, and then will iterate again on the resulting enumerable to find the `Min`. Run this: `char min = array.Where(c => c > findNextBiggestValue).Min(c => { ("Accessed " + c).Dump(); return c; });`. It will do one iteration (best case, no elements are bigger than `findNextBiggestValue`) up to two iterations (worst case, all elements are bigger)

Comment: Your code throw exception if `array` does not have any elements bigger than `findNextBiggestValue`.

Comment: @Rob - It is only one iteration. The source values from the array are only iterated once. This is true no matter how many where clauses are chained together.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Yes, that is by design. `char` can't be `null` so to return any other value for be misleading and most likely a bug. So the choice is to change the return type to `char?` or to raise an exception. I chose the latter.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, it's only one iteration of the *source*, but that's misleading. It still will take `N` -> `2N` evaluations, which is not `N` (saying it's only one iteration) and is not an insignificant difference if the array is large

Comment: @Rob - But it's still `O(n)` complexity, not `O(2n)` or `O(n^2)`. I was comparing with a sort which is at least `O(nlogn)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to sort the array, let's try this way.

```
    char findNextBiggestValue = '4';
    char[] array = {'3', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    // No elemnt? Do nothing
    if (array.Length < 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Init it a large value
    char minValue = 'z';

    // Look for the next bigger value
    foreach (var c in array)
    {
        if (findNextBiggestValue < c && c < minValue)
        {
            minValue = c;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(minValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

array.FirstOrDefault(x => x > '4')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FirstOrDefault extension method to achieve this:

```
 array.FirstOrDefault(m=> int.Parse(m.ToString()) > int.Parse(findNextBiggestValue.ToString());
```